# Getting current timezone name in Delphi

Tags: delphi, timezone

How can I get the current timezone **name** in Delphi ?
I mean, not the timezoneinfo, that I get via  "getTimeZoneInformation"
but the name (as defined in the registry) of the current timezone,
that is, the current subkey of hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\timezones ?
Regards
Maurizio

Comment: You actually need to enumerate the system timezones and for each retrieve its name. I've checked MSDN but couldn't find any function for that. For instance.NET [`retrieves available timezones`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,443c9b06db11142b) from registry, so I would suggest the same.

Comment: @TLama - Can there be more than one system timezone? Isn't it enough to look at the registry key of the 'StandardName' of 'TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION' that 'GetTimeZoneInformation' fills?

Comment: @Sertac, there's a lot of timezones in the system; `GetTimeZoneInformation` is unfortunately made to return only current. I would suggest to enumerate all the subkeys of the mentioned reg. key and as .NET does in its internal [`TryGetLocalizedNamesByRegistryKey`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,859af666a20ff472) function, read the names from the DLL resource (pointed by the `MUI_Std` reg. value), and if that fails, read the `Std` reg. value.